# Marcel Proust and Markov decipher security service’s T9 texts

Tags: code-golf, string, cipher, markov-chain

As if this challenge could be any more [Pythonesque](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uwAOc4g3K-g) in spirit... **No prior knowledge of Markov chains or encryption techniques is required.**

You are a spy who needs to obtain some crucial information from the British security service M1S. The agents of M1S are well aware that their Wi-Fi signals can be intercepted, their Android/iOS security vulnerabilities exploited etc., so all of them are using Nokia 3310’s to transmit text information which is typed using the **T9 auto-completion**.

You had previously hacked the phones to be delivered to the intelligence agency and had installed keyloggers under their glorious plastic keyboards, so now you receive sequences of numbers corresponding to the letters they typed, so “[the eagle has left the nest alert the agents](https://xkcd.com/733/)” becomes

```
84303245304270533808430637802537808430243687
```

But wait! Some T9 sequences are ambiguous (“6263” could be “name”, “mane” or “oboe”; the more obscure, the more suspicious it gets!), so what do you do? You know that the only entrance examination M1S uses is summarising Marcel Proust’s masterpiece “Remembrance of Things Past” in 15 seconds, so you want to pick the word that comes next after the previous one according to its frequency distribution in the entire chef-d’œuvre of Proust!

*Can you crack the code and obtain what could be the original message?*

### The principle of T9

[image: Nokia 3310 keyboards used by the agents]

The T9 auto-completion mechanism can be described as follows. It maps alphabetic characters to numbers as shown on the picture above.

```
abc     -> 2
def     -> 3
ghi     -> 4
jkl     -> 5
mno     -> 6
pqrs    -> 7
tuv     -> 8
wxyz    -> 9
<space> -> 0
<other> -> <is deleted>
```

The T9 decryptor receives a sequence of digits and tries to guess the word that could be typed with those keypresses. It might use a standard frequency table, but we are going one step further and predicting the next word using a Markov chain!

### Learning sample

The corpus is [this heavily stripped version of Proust’s “Remembrance of Things Past”](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Fifis/proust/master/proust.txt) (`s/-/ /g`, `s/['’]s //g` and `s/[^a-zA-Z ]//g` — begone confusing possessive `'s`!) originally published on the [University of Adelaide website](https://ebooks.adelaide.edu.au/p/proust/marcel/) (the text of this work is in the Public Domain in Australia).

The whole text **must be analysed as one string, as one long sentence, as one long vector of words** (whichever is more convenient for your language), **stripped of linebreaks**, and **split into words at spaces**. (I do not supply a single-paragraph file because such might be frowned upon by github tools.)

How do I read the whole text as one string / sentence? An example in **R**:

```
p_raw  <- read.table("proust.txt", sep="\t") # Because there are no tabs
p_vec  <- as.character(p_raw$V1)       # Conversion to character vector
p_str  <- paste(p_vec, collapse=" ")   # One long string with spaces
p_spl  <- strsplit(p_str, split=" ")[[1]] # Vector of 1360883 words
proust <- p_spl[p_spl!=""]           # Remove empty entries — 1360797
```

### Task

Given a sequence of digits as a number, return a possible text string that could be typed using the corresponding T9 keys using a probabilty chain to predict the next word *X* based on [this training text](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Fifis/proust/master/proust.txt) treated as one long sentence.

If *X* is the first T9-word of the text and there are multiple guesses, pick one at random, otherwise pick the only one possible.

For all subsequent T9-words *X(i)* preceded by a word already deciphered *w(i-1)*:

1. If a T9-word *X* can be converted into a normal word *x* in one unique way, do it.
2. If there are multiple conversion options available for *X*, say *x1, x2, ...*, look up the preceding guessed word *w*.

   - If *w* is never followed by anything that maps to *X* in the original work of Proust, pick any of the possible *x1, x2, ...* at random.
   - If *w X* always corresponds to *w x1* in the original and there are no concurrent *xi*’s that could be mapped into *X*, pick *x1*.
   - If *w X* can be converted to *w x1*, *w x2*, ... that can be found in the corpus, then count all possible *xi*’s that follow *w* and map to *X* in the corpus and pick *xi* with probability *xi/(x1 + x2 + ...)*.

**Example 2a.** If the message is `76630489`, where `489` could be `guy` or `ivy` (they occur in the corpus at least once), `7663` can be deciphered as `some` (a very probable first word). If `some` is never followed by anything that maps to `489` in the corpus, then pick `guy` or `ivy` at random with probability 0.5.

**Example 2b.** If the message is `766302277437`, where `2277437` could be `barrier` or `carrier`, `7663` can be deciphered as `some`. If Proust always used `some carrier` and never `some barrier`, then pick `some carrier`.

**Example 2c.** Suppose that you want to decipher the sequence `536307663`. `5363` was predicted as `lend`. `7663` could be any of these: `pond`, `roof` and `some`. You count the occurrences of the word following `lend` in the sample corpus. Suppose you get something like this (just to illustrate):

```
        T9  Word following lend  Occurrences
      7663  some                           7
      7663  pond                           2
      7663  roof                           1
```

So if `7663` is preceded by `lend`, there is `7/(7+2+1)=70%` probability that `7663` stands for `some`, 20% `pond` and 10% `roof`. Your algorithm should produce `lend some` in 70% cases, `lend pond` in 20% cases etc.

You may safely assume that the agents use **only a-z letters and spaces** (no punctuation marks, no possessive `'s`, and no numbers).

You may also assume that the agents of M1S **never use any words outside the scope of “Remembrance of Things Past”** (which is a whopping vocabulary of 29,237 words!).

The T9 fuctionality was implemented in [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/42220/194), so you might have a look at it.

If you need any help, probabilistic chains were gloriously tamed in [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3108/using-a-markov-chain-because-this-question-itself-as-input-text-for-example), [that](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3726/markov-chain-beatbox-generator) and [the following](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/75673/na%c3%afve-markov-chain-word-generation) challenges, but you do not even need to know the principle of such chains: everything is stated in the task.

### Test cases

```
--Inputs--
20784250276960369
20784250276960369
84303245304270533808430637802537808430243687
94280343084306289072908608430262780482737
94280343084306289072908608430262780482737

--Possible outputs--
c quick brown fox
a stick crown fox
the eagle gas left the nest blest vie agents
what did the navy pay to the coast guards
what did the navy raz un the coast guards
```

### Rules:

- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply.
- You do not know the original message, all you get is a sequence of digits and the file [proust.txt](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Fifis/proust/master/proust.txt) that you just need to load in the memory / workspace / whatever. There is no need to have anything self-contained; assume `proust.txt` is always accessible.
- Your algorithm must be able to produce different outputs with respective probabilities if more than one decryption option is probable according to the corpus (see Example 2c).

You need to stay as discreet as possible, so the shortest code wins!

**P.S.** The obvious benefit of this probabilistic algorithm is the fact that the probability you will get a true original string for an ambiguous deciphered string tends to one — just wait...

**P.P.S.**  See also [Prediction by Partial Matching](http://compressions.sourceforge.net/PPM.html).

Comment: [Peter Taylor’s](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/194/peter-taylor) remarks from the sandbox were taken into account. Sadly, very few people responded during the week it had been posted there despite multiple updates, so any suggestions are welcome! BTW, this is my first challenge!

Comment: I suspect that a big reason you didn't get many responses is because of the advanced knowledge needed to understand this problem.  If you *are* wanting this challenge to appeal to a larger crowd, I'd recommend including some earlier examples that show the markov chain at work :)

Comment: @NathanMerrill OK, I added 3 links to sample challenges. However, a user need not know Markov chains at all because the task is described in the question body as algorithmically as possible: if X, do Y with probabilities obtained by calculating Z in this learning sample. I tried to make it as self-sufficient as it gets...

Comment: Oh, I understand.  If you didn't explain it, I would have voted to close it.  It just *looks* like it needs advanced knowledge :)

Comment: @NathanMerrill Well, verbosity will kill me some day...

Comment: I like this challenge, but I haven't had time to sit down and create/golf a solution yet. Hopefully that will happen soon.

Comment: Reference that might be of interest for this challenge: [Prediction by Partial Matching](http://compressions.sourceforge.net/PPM.html)

Comment: IMHO, a dictionary of 29K words looks excessive for this format. It's already more than 100K once zipped and I don't feel like building a trie or a DAG on so many entries. I'd suggest to limit the training text to a few relevant paragraphs.

Comment: @Arnauld Referenced that PPM article. However, the dictionary must be so huge because of the rule **2c**: if there are multiple decryption options possible **and** such sequences had occurred in the text before... There is very low probability that the exact two words go enought times one after another in the learning text (except such popular cases as “said to”). Proust never wrote “brown fox”. I wish I could make the learning sample larger just to estimate the probabilities of the real-world language and thought “RoTP” was big enough (in fact, it is not... where’s my “brown fox”, then?).

Comment: Are we expected to encode the data from the Proust corpus into our solution?  Given the size of the text file, that would seem to bias the solutions toward data compression rather than the word selection aspects of the task.  On the other hand, it the text file is an assumed input, the solutions could focus on building and using a data structure to perform the   steps as stated in the task.

Comment: @RootTwo No, no! It will suffice to provide a function that outputs the deciphered text on the fly. You are encouraged to read and find occurrences in `proust.txt` only as a necessary step for prediction... there is no need to output a data structure, a matrix of probabilities or a matrix of follow-ups and precedences between any two words. Your function may “forget” what it had calculated after outputting a string. Seems that I should post my own (non-competing) solution in order to encourage other people...

Comment: @Andrei My solution is a function of two parameters, the message to decode and the file name of the corpus ("proust.txt").  It reads the corpus and then decodes and prints the message.  My question was whether that would be an acceptable answer.  Can the solution read proust.txt or does the solution need to be self contained?

Comment: @RootTwo I should update the specification: the solution may read `proust.txt` — and in fact it should. Therefore, you may treat the file `proust.txt` as a pre-existing set of strings that you just need to load in the memory / workspace / whatever. There is no need to have anything self-contained; assume `proust.txt` is always accessible.

Answer (score 1):

### R solution, non-competing illustration of what can be done

Firstly, we load the sequence of words into the memory:

```
p_raw  <- read.table("proust.txt", sep="\t") # Because there are no tabs
p_vec  <- as.character(p_raw$V1)       # Conversion to character vector
p_str  <- paste(p_vec, collapse=" ")   # One long string with spaces
p_spl  <- strsplit(p_str, split=" ")[[1]] # Vector of 1360883 words
proust <- p_spl[p_spl!=""]           # Remove empty entries — 1360797
```

Secondly, we need a function that T9-ifies any text:

```
t9 <- function (x) {
  x <- chartr(paste(c(letters, " "), collapse=""), "222333444555666777788899990", tolower(x))
  x <- gsub("[^0-9]", "", x, perl = TRUE) # Safety check
  x <- x[x!=""] # Also for safety because... you know...
  x
}
```

Then, we T9-ify Proust:

```
p9 <- t9(proust)
```

Final preparation: we split the input string at zeros using a function that we call `prep`):

```
prep <- function (x) {
  x <- chartr("0", " ", x)
  x <- strsplit(x, " ")[[1]]
  x <- x[x!=""] # Boil the empty strings for safety
  x
}
```

And now I propose a function that takes any input string of numbers, `prep`s it and deciphers the words one by one:

```
decip <- function(x, verbose = FALSE) {
  x <- prep(x)
  l <- length(x)
  decrypted <- rep(NA, l)
  tb <- table(proust[which(p9 == x[1])])
  decrypted[1] <- sample(names(tb), 1, prob=tb/sum(tb))
  if (verbose) print(decrypted[1])
  for (i in 2:l) {
    mtchl <- p9 == x[i]
    mtch <- which(mtchl)  # Positions that matched
    pmtch <- proust[mtch] # Words that matched
    tb <- table(pmtch)    # Count occurrences that matched
    if (length(tb)==1) {  # It is either 1 or >1
      decrypted[i] <- names(tb)[1]
      if (verbose) print(paste0("i = ", i, ", case 1: unique decryption"))
      } else {  # If there are more than one ways to decipher...
      preced <- proust[mtch-1] 
      s <- sum(preced==decrypted[i-1])
      if (s==0) {
        decrypted[i] <- sample(names(tb), 1)
        if (verbose) print(paste0("i = ", i, ", case 2a: multiple decryption, collocation never used, picking at random"))
        } else {
        tb2 <- table(pmtch[preced==decrypted[i-1]])
        if (length(tb2)==1) {
          decrypted[i] <-  names(tb2)[1]
          if (verbose) print(paste0("i = ", i, ", case 2b: multiple decryption, only one collocation found, using it"))
        } else {
          decrypted[i] <- sample(names(tb2), 1, prob = tb2/sum(tb2))
          if (verbose) print(paste0("i = ", i, ", case 2c: multiple decryption, ", length(tb2), " choices"))
          }
      }
    }
    if(verbose) print(decrypted[i])
  }
  decrypted
}
```

And now what it is actually doing:

```
decip("20784250276960369", verbose=TRUE)
----
[1] "a"
[1] "i = 2, case 2c: multiple decryption, 2 choices"
[1] "quick"
[1] "i = 3, case 2a: multiple decryption, collocation never used, picking at random"
[1] "brown"
[1] "i = 4, case 1: unique decryption"
[1] "fox"
[1] "a"     "quick" "brown" "fox"
```

Second example:

```
decip("84303245304270533808430637802537808430243687", verbose=TRUE)
----
[1] "what"
[1] "i = 2, case 2b: multiple decryption, only one collocation found, using it"
[1] "did"
[1] "i = 3, case 2b: multiple decryption, only one collocation found, using it"
[1] "the"
[1] "i = 4, case 1: unique decryption"
[1] "navy"
[1] "i = 5, case 2a: multiple decryption, collocation never used, picking at random"
[1] "raz"
[1] "i = 6, case 2a: multiple decryption, collocation never used, picking at random"
[1] "um"
[1] "i = 7, case 2a: multiple decryption, collocation never used, picking at random"
[1] "the"
[1] "i = 8, case 2b: multiple decryption, only one collocation found, using it"
[1] "coast"
[1] "i = 9, case 1: unique decryption"
[1] "guards"
[1] "what"   "did"    "the"    "navy"   "raz"    "um"     "the"    "coast"  "guards"
```

Please do not comment that this can be golfed. Seems that few people are interested in this challenge because of my terrible verbosity, so I posted this answer to show what a possible programme could look like. You need not upvote/downvote this answer.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 316 bytes

```
from random import*
from collections import*
def d(s,f):
 D=defaultdict(Counter);p=q=''
 for w in open(f).read().split():D[w.translate({97+c:(c-(c>17)-(c>24))//3+50for c in range(26)})].update([w]);D[p].update([w]);p=w
 for c in s.split('0'):q=choice([*(len(D[c])>1and D[c]&D[q]or D[c]).elements()]);print(q,end=' ')
```